# Using SCSS/SASS with Dojotoolkit

Tags: sass, dojo

Is there a way to use sass/scss with Dojotoolkit ?

I've searched for any documentation, tutorial or references but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you really need to do.

Generally Dojo Themes like Claro are based on LESS CSS preprocessor, Dojo Flat instead use Stylus.

So if you need to modify or fork Dojo Themes you should stick to LESS or Stylus.

If instead you do not need to modify a Dojo Themes and just simply need add your CSS for anything else you could use with no problem SCSS/SASS.

I would suggest in that case to process your styles using a separate "tasks", example you could use [gulp-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass) or similar.

Comment: So I can't use directly. I have to use a build tool (maybe dojo's own build tool) to compile the scss and generate the css files. Is that it ?

Comment: To build SCSS/SASS you do not need to use the dojo's own build tools. You can use any "task" runners like gulp or grant and just add your postprocess CSS to the document's head.
If you are customizing a Dojo Theme, example Claro, you can follow this tutorial https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/themes.html

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira If you think my answer was helpfulp please do not forget to up-vote or accept it ;) thanks

Comment: Yes I already use Grunt in other project and love it. I just thought as I'm sticking with Dojo, it would be better to use it's own tools.